# Why isn't my page redirecting after video?

Tags: html, redirect, video

Why isn't my page redirecting after the video finishes? Currently, it is live at https://www.eves.website/eve_3.html

After the video finishes, it is supposed to go to https://www.eves.website/eve_4.html
Which is also live. But it just says on eve_3. html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>eve_</title>
<link rel="icon" rel="preload" href="images/evecircle.png" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){   
   $("#myVideo").bind('ended', function(){
      location.href="https://www.eves.website/eve_4.html";   
   }); 
  });
</script>
</head>
  <body>

<video id="myVideo" style="margin-left:-10px; margin-top:-10px;" width="105%" height="105%" autoplay>
  <source src="images/human.mp4" autoplay="true" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("#myVideo").bind('ended', function(){
      window.location.href="https://www.eves.website/eve_4.html";   
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because it wasn't secure, therefore it wasn't allowing me to redirect to another site.